# How to enable network interface after attaching ENI to any given instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-interface

I have service running on multiple hosts(EC2 Ubuntu 16.x). And we are trying to attach new network interface (ENI) to the some of node.

We are are able to create new network interface and attach/use for the given instance. But even after attaching we are unable to use the IP outside of that instance. So we are unable to access the secondary IP outside the server.

Please suggest with the steps for enabling attached secondary index.

Thanks and regards,
Umesh Dc

Comment: Can you ping the new IP from the host itself? Have you checked that the new network interface is present in the security groups, and the traffic is not blocked to this interface?

Comment: Yes I can ping new IP from host itself, but unable to connect from any other instance in the same VPC.

Comment: Have you enabled relevant ports with the new Interface in the security groups, especially the inbound rules ?